# How to create one overall network with two wireless signals (one public, one private)

Tags: wireless-networking

What I want to do:

I want to have one overall network but with two wireless signals. I want one to be public while the other is private.

What I know I need:

I know I need two wireless routers and then my modem. I know that the wireless routers will need to connect to my modem. I am not sure if there is any other hardware that I will need.

How I think I will create this network:

Once I have all of the hardware I need, I will connect my routers to my modem and then I will configure the settings on the routers for the access.

I am not sure if that is correct. If it is correct, how I do configure one to be public and the other private?

Comment: By public you mean open?

Comment: [1]: http://www.techspot.com/guides/287-default-router-ip-addresses/
  [2]: http://superuser.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=connect%20two%20routers
  [3]: http://superuser.com/questions/218467/how-to-create-an-open-wireless-along-with-private-wireless
  [4]: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-two-routers-off-one-cable-connection-56718.html